# Reuse a named uwsgi location in nginx

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I have an nginx server that has several code paths to a uwsgi proxy, in order to enforce server-wide HTTPS along with several path-based exceptions. Is there a way to reuse a location containing the uwsgi configuration in several path-based locations, or can my configuration could be rethought to simplify it?

### Functional Requirements

I need to enforce HTTPS (As defined by the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header) globally on the domain `www.example.net`, with the following exceptions:

- `www.example.com/legacy/`
- `www.example.com/api/webhook/`

### Working Configuration

The following code works, but it is not DRY because of the repetition of the uwsgi configuration parameters.

```
server {
  listen 8054;
  server_name www.example.net;

  #
  # HTTPS Exceptions
  #

  location /legacy/ {
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/uwsgi/socket.sock;
  }

  location /api/webhook/ {
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/uwsgi/socket.sock;
  }

  #
  # Primary uwsgi proxy
  #
  location / {
    #
    # Enforce HTTPS
    #
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
      return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/uwsgi/socket.sock;
  }
}
```

### Non-working Configuration

The following configuration **does not work** (specifically, a named location is not a valid argument to `return`), but sketches out how I'd like to move to a more reusable uwsgi configuration.

```
#
# Reusable uwsgi configuration
#
location @python {
  include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/uwsgi/socket.sock;
}

server {
  listen 8054;
  server_name www.example.net;

  #
  # HTTPS Exceptions
  #

  location /legacy/ {
    return @python;
  }

  location /api/webhook/ {
    return @python;
  }

  #
  # Primary site entry point
  #
  location / {
    #
    # Enforce HTTPS
    #
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
      return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    return @python;
  }
}
```

Thanks very much for taking the time to read this.